# How to group agents in NetLogo and ask them to stay in group while foraging?

Tags: grouping, netlogo

I have slightly problem in keeping a group of agents moving together in NetLogo world

Here is what I want to do. I want them to stay in group while moving, the rules to keep them in groups are BOIDS, which I'm gonna apply "separate,cohere and align" codes within groups.

Here is my code. 
This is global code

```
globals[                  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;global variables;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
  t-bp                        ;;time taken in ticks
  t-time                      ;;time taken in seconds
  groups
]
```

Here is what the turtles has

```
  turtles-own[               
  food-found         
  on-food            
  see-food           
  my-group
]
```

this is setup code

```
   to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape turtles "arrow"

   ask turtles                          ;;;;;agents setup;;;;;;;;
  [ set size 2.0
    set color blue
    set count-down 30
    set happy? set?
    set on-food 0
    set see-food 0
  ]
 let number-of-groups 5
  let turtles-per-group 4  
  create-turtles turtles-per-group * number-of-groups 

  set groups [] ; empty list
  repeat number-of-groups [
    let new-group n-of turtles-per-group turtles with [
      not is-agentset? my-group
    ]
    ask new-group [ set my-group new-group ]
    set groups lput new-group groups
  ]

  print (word "First group:  " sort first groups)
  print (word "Second group: " sort last groups)
  ask turtles [ show sort other my-group ]
end
```

after they found their group, they need to follow their group around.
here is to go code

```
to go  
                                      ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;agents procedure;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
  ask turtles 

 [  call-eat                                     ;;;;;;;turtle movement;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ifelse food > 0
   [stay]          ;;eat food;;
   [continue            ;;walk to other places to find food;;
    turn-towards]

   ;;;;setup for agents foraging styles;
    if (Forage-style = "Eat,Inspect and Stop") [set Scale -30]
    if (Forage-style = "Eat and Walk") [set Scale 0]
    if (Forage-style = "Stop and Eat") [set Scale -15]

ask turtle 1
[if not any? patches with [food > 0]
  [
    show ticks stop]
  ]
end
```

this is how I code them to walk throughout world

```
to walk                                                                                    
if any? patches in-cone vision-distance 40 with [food > 0]  [set see-food 1
    face min-one-of patches in-cone vision-distance 40 with [food > 0][distance myself]
      fd distance min-one-of patches in-cone vision-distance 40 with [food > 0][distance myself] * 0.002]
end
```

The problem is, I don't know how to move them in group and where to apply BOIDS.

And if I want agents to check patches without food, is this the right way?

```
ask turtle 1
[if not any? patches with [food > 0]
  [
    show ticks stop]
  ]
end
```

Ways to group agents within group is answered in this post 
[How to send parameters using NetLogo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240262/how-to-send-parameters-using-netlogo/46241401?noredirect=1#comment79523176_46241401)

Thank you.

Comment: This is a pretty involved question, and Stack Overflow is more intended to answer specific coding issues- you will likely get more traction if you provide examples of what you have already tried. Have a look at the [asking help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some guidelines. Have you looked at the Flocking model in the Model Library? Behavior there is similar to BOIDS, maybe it could get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my question. :D